# Problem with building Linux for the RISC-V target

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, compilation, riscv

Hello to all there i'm installing the tools for RISCV:

https://risc-v-getting-started-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linux-qemu.html

According the documentation:

https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain

I configured de PATH

```
export RISCV=/opt/riscv
export PATH=$PATH:$RISCV/bin
```

and after i installed the Tool chain and qemu

when i will compile linux kernell i run these commands:

```
cd linux 
git checkout v5.4.0 
make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig
```

But i got these errors:

```
*** Default configuration is based on 'defconfig' scripts/Kconfig.include:35: compiler 'riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' not found make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:83: defconfig] Error 1 make: *** [Makefile:567: defconfig] Error 2
```

I think that i successfully installed qemu but i am having problems with the other two packages (Linux and busybox due a the error above).

Thank you

Comment: Looks like it can't find the RISCV cross-compiler.  Ad it to PATH

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm new on Linux how can i verify the compiler and add it to the PATH?

Answer (score 1):

I think you wrote the part

```
export RISCV=/opt/riscv
export PATH=$PATH:$RISCV/bin
```

to the command line.  When you insert it to the command line it saves the PATH in only current bash. You should change the `PATH` from the `.bashrc` in the `home` directory to change for all bash execution. I think during the compilation they are other operations in background that cannot see the added directory to `PATH` in your bash window.
Be sure to see hidden files because `.bashrc` is a hidden one.